# Google Drive SDK Error

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

This is my code to access Google Drive, taken largely from **ArtOfWarfare** in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk/12321331#comment18575553_12321331) post:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
        boolean alreadyTriedAgain;
        public OnTokenAcquired() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == 3025) {
                switch (resultCode) {
                case RESULT_OK:
                    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
                    am.getAuthToken(am.getAccounts()[0],
                            "ouath2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE,
                            new Bundle(),
                            true,
                            new OnTokenAcquired(),
                            null);
                    break;
                case RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // This probably means the user refused to log in. Explain to them why they need to log in.
                    break;
                default:
                    // This isn't expected... maybe just log whatever code was returned.
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                // Your application has other intents that it fires off besides the one for Drive's log in if it ever reaches this spot. Handle it here however you'd like.
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
            try {
                final String token = result.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
                JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
                Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
                b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                        DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
                        driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
                        driveRequest.setKey("my number here");
                        driveRequest.setOauthToken(token);
                    }
                });

                final Drive drive = b.build();

                final com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
                body.setTitle("My Test File");
                body.setDescription("A Test File");
                body.setMimeType("text/plain");
                File newFile = new File("this");
                final FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", newFile);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = drive.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                            alreadyTriedAgain = false; // Global boolean to make sure you don't repeatedly try too many times when the server is down or your code is faulty... they'll block requests until the next day if you make 10 bad requests, I found.
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            if (!alreadyTriedAgain) {
                                alreadyTriedAgain = true;
                                AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
                                am.invalidateAuthToken(am.getAccounts()[0].type, null); // Requires the permissions MANAGE_ACCOUNTS & USE_CREDENTIALS in the Manifest
                                am.getAuthToken(am.getAccounts()[0],
                                        "ouath2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE,
                                        new Bundle(),
                                        true,
                                        new OnTokenAcquired(),
                                        null);
                            } else {
                                // Give up. Crash or log an error or whatever you want.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
                Intent launch = (Intent)result.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                if (launch != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(launch, 3025);
                    return; // Not sure why... I wrote it here for some reason. Might not actually be necessary.
                }
            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                // Handle it...
            } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                // Handle it...
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle it...
            }
        }

    }
    private java.io.File downloadGFileToJFolder(Drive drive, String token, File gFile, java.io.File jFolder) throws IOException {
        if (gFile.toURI() != null && gFile.toURI().toString().length() > 0 ) {
            if (jFolder == null) {
                jFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                jFolder.mkdirs();
            }
            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(gFile.toURI());
                get.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                jFolder.mkdirs();
                java.io.File jFile = new java.io.File(jFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + gFile.getName()); // getGFileName() is my own method... it just grabs originalFilename if it exists or title if it doesn't.
                FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(jFile);
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length=inputStream.read(buffer))>0) {
                    fileStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                fileStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                return jFile;
            } catch (IOException e) {        
                // Handle IOExceptions here...
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the file on Google Drive has no length here.
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getApplicationContext();
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
        am.getAuthToken(am.getAccounts()[0],
                "ouath2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE,
                new Bundle(),
                true,
                new OnTokenAcquired(),
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I get the following error when I launch the app (Android System also stops momentarily):

```
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/android.accounts.GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.accounts.GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity.onCreate(GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity.java:84)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
11-26 22:31:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4288):     ... 11 more
```

In addition, my phone shows a strange notification: `"Permission Requested for account Weather"`. Anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Have you signed in to the Google Drive app on this phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
am.getAccounts()[0],
```

with this:

```
am.getAccountsByType("com.google")[0],
```

My code in the other topic was over simplified to assume that the first account it found would be a Google Account (and so have a Google Drive). The code we actually used in the app checked to make sure it was a Google Account (and then performed further checks to make sure it was a company account, which is why I simplified the code to what I shared.)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your answer. This guide was just published (yesterday, I think): https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android, and I was able to get it to work very simply using that.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it today. I guess I was off by a few weeks when I predicted in September that Google wouldn't have a decent guide for using the Drive API on Android until next year. Hopefully their guide doesn't render mine useless.

Comment: As long as your company's app keeps running, I suppose it doesn't much matter.

Comment: If anyone else has to ever update my code at my company, they may be quite confused if my ways differ from Google's. But yeah, as long as the app keeps running, then it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: If you're worried about that, why not update it? I'm sure your firm would only encourage it.

Comment: i just try quickstart sample i have some error please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636659/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-google-play-serivces-libwithout-supporting-ja